# Assistance with a python function that accepts an array as a parameter

Tags: python

I am requesting assistance with a HW assignment that determines the BMI of a set of names and output whether or not that name is underweight, normal weight, or overweight.
This is my program so far and the part that I am having trouble with is the function at the end.

```
#function to calculate bmi
def bmi(weight, height):
    return weight * 703 / height ** 2

name_list = ['Spiderman', 'Ironman', 'Black Widow', 'Hulk', 'Thanos', 'Shuri']

#prompting the user for the height of the individuals
heights = []
for name in name_list:
    heights.append(int(input(f"Please input the height in inches for {name}: ")))

#prompting the user for the weight of the individuals
weights = []
for name in name_list:
    weights.append(int(input(f"Please input the weight in pounds for {name}: ")))

#outputting the BMI for each individual
for i, name in enumerate(name_list):
    print(f"The BMI for {name} is {bmi(weights[i], heights[i])}.")

#appending the BMI to a new list
bmi_list = []
for i, name in enumerate(name_list):
        bmi_list.append((bmi(weights[i], heights[i])))
        
#function to calculate if the person is underweight, normal weight, or overweight.
#BMI of <= 18 is underweight, BMI of >= 19 and <=25 is normal and BMI of >26 is overweight
def calc(bmi_list):
    for i in bmi_list:
        if i <= 18:
            print(f"{name} is underweight.")
        if i >= 19 and i <= 25:
            print(f"{name} is normal weight.")
        if i >= 26:
            print(f"{name} is overweight.")
calc(bmi_list)
```

The output for the last function is

```
Shuri is normal weight.
Shuri is normal weight.
Shuri is normal weight.
Shuri is normal weight.
Shuri is underweight.
Shuri is underweight.
```

whereas, I need it to output like this:

```
Spiderman is normal weight.
Ironman is normal weight.
Black Widow is normal weight.
Hulk is normal weight.
Thanos is underweight.
Shuri is underweight.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over `name_list` rather than just use the variable `name` (which has the last value left from the `for i, name` loop). You can use `zip()` to loop over both lists together.

```
def calc(name_list, bmi_list):
    for i, name in zip(bmi_list, name_list):
        if i <= 18:
            print(f"{name} is underweight.")
        elif i <= 25:
            print(f"{name} is normal weight.")
        else:
            print(f"{name} is overweight.")

calc(name_list, bmi_list)
```

You should also use `elif and` else` for mutually exclusive conditions.

It's generally easier not to have separate lists for each attribute. Instead, make a list of tuples or dictionaries so all the related information is together.